# Android Studio: AVD Manager UI completely different suddenly

Tags: android, user-interface, interface, android-virtual-device

I recently had to reinstall Android Studio as a last ditch attempt to fix the "java_find.exe not found" bug. Unfortunately, this new build seems to have a radically different AVD interface that makes me unable to configure a lot of aspects of my virtual devices that I would have been able to with the original format and worse seems to only create emulated devices that never progress past the boot-up screen. After an extensive amount of google-ing I seem to be the only one on the planet who has this interface, so any explanation or advice would be massively appreciated.

[image]

(EDIT) Here's an image of an emulated device I just made. For the API I have no other option other than different versions of 21. In this case I chose the first option.

[image]

[image]

However, the same problem still persists where the emulator never progresses past the android screen. (It's been running for 10 minutes now when before my emulators would start in less than two.)

I've also just noticed this error hidden way in the bottom left corner of android studio.

"Could not find a matching system image for ABI x86, API 19/null: Could not find a matching system image for ABI x86, API 19/null"

Could this be related at all?

Comment: I just checked, i have it too. Installed android studio last week. v0.8.14

Comment: why don't  you use "android avd" command then?

Comment: "makes me unable to configure a lot of aspects of my virtual devices that I would have been able to with the original format" -- such as?

Comment: The left pane shows you selected "Phone" but the middle pane doesn't show you've selected a device/profile (confirmed by the right pane which says "No Device Selected").

Answer (score 0):

*After an extensive amount of google-ing I seem to be the only one on the planet who has this interface*

Fear not! I have the same screen. I installed android studio last week and I'm on the Beta version 0.8.14

*Unfortunately, this new build seems to have a radically different AVD interface that makes me unable to configure a lot of aspects of my virtual devices that I would have been able to with the original format **and worse seems to only create emulated devices that never progress past the boot-up screen**.*

I just created an AVD for the sole purpose of trying to recreate the issue. I created an AVD with a Nexus 4 and api 19 (kitkat 4.4.2), then booted it by pressing the play button in the `Actions` area.

It did take a couple mins (~4) but eventually it booted and now works fine.

*any explanation or advice would be massively appreciated.*

Explanation: sadly don't have one
Advice: reinstall and see what happens. Or show me your actual virtual devices screen so I can try and reproduce your errors.

**Edit**

I created a new AVD with the same specs as yours, and it booted fine.

Do you have these system images installed? (in SDK manager) or at least the one(s) you are trying to use for your AVD

[image]

Comment: I've updated the question with some more images, thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: @Liam see my edit, i suspect it has to do with your sdk missing system images for the avd processor